# POSTGRESQL: ON UPDATE CASCADE is not working as expected

Tags: postgresql

I'm having difficult to understand the desired behavior of ON UPDATE CASCADE
when one field is nullable and it's reference is updated.

In the following example of tables city and statistic, when we have a city and it's province has no value (NULL) the trigger ON UPDATE CASCADE does not work properly while I was expecting it to update the province value on statistics.

When we run a update on city with EXPLAIN we can easily see this behaivor.

Note: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.8

**Creating the tables to reproduce the case**

```
CREATE TABLE city (
    id            BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name          VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    country_id    BIGINT NOT NULL,
    province_id   BIGINT,

    CONSTRAINT city_city_country_province_un UNIQUE (id, country_id, province_id)
);

CREATE TABLE statistics (
    id            BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    city_id       BIGINT NOT NULL,
    country_id    BIGINT NOT NULL,
    province_id   BIGINT,
    some_data     INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    CONSTRAINT statistics_city_country_province_fk FOREIGN KEY (city_id, country_id, province_id) REFERENCES city (id, country_id, province_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT statistics_city_un UNIQUE (city_id)
);
```

**Populating tables**

```
INSERT INTO city (name, country_id, province_id) VALUES ('SAO CARLOS', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO city (name, country_id, province_id) VALUES ('VATICAN CITY', 2, NULL);

INSERT INTO statistics (city_id, country_id, province_id) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO statistics (city_id, country_id, province_id) VALUES (2, 1, NULL);
```

**Updating city when province is NOT NULL**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE UPDATE city SET province_id = 3 WHERE id = 1;
```

**QUERY PLAN**

```
Update on public.city  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=168) (actual time=0.238..0.238 rows=0 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using city_city_country_province_un on public.city  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=168) (actual time=0.046..0.048 rows=1 loops=1)
     Output: id, name, country_id, 3::bigint, ctid
     Index Cond: (city.id = 1)
Planning time: 0.510 ms
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_41406 for constraint statistics_city_country_province_fk on city: time=0.792 calls=1
Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_41408 for constraint statistics_city_country_province_fk on statistics: time=0.296 calls=1
Execution time: 1.412 ms
```

**city after the update**

```
 id | city_id | country_id | province_id | some_data
----+---------+------------+-------------+-----------
  1 |       1 |          1 |           3 |         0
  2 |       2 |          2 |             |         0
```

**statistics after the update**

```
 id | city_id | country_id | province_id | some_data
----+---------+------------+-------------+-----------
  1 |       1 |          1 |           3 |         0
  2 |       2 |          2 |             |         0
```

**Updating city when province is NULL**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE UPDATE city SET province_id = 7 WHERE id = 2;
```

**QUERY PLAN**

```
Update on public.city  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=168) (actual time=0.170..0.170 rows=0 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using city_city_country_province_un on public.city  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=168) (actual time=0.042..0.044 rows=1 loops=1)
     Output: id, name, country_id, 7::bigint, ctid
     Index Cond: (city.id = 2)
Planning time: 0.423 ms
Execution time: 0.225 ms
```

**city after the update**

```
 id |     name     | country_id | province_id
----+--------------+------------+-------------
  1 | SAO CARLOS   |          1 |           3
  2 | VATICAN CITY |          2 |           7
```

**statistics after the update**

```
 id | city_id | country_id | province_id | some_data
----+---------+------------+-------------+-----------
  1 |       1 |          1 |           3 |         0
  2 |       2 |          2 |             |         0
```

**EDIT: work arround to update when the field is `NULL`**

**Create a function to update when old value is `NULL`**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_null_province_reference() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (OLD.province_id IS NULL AND NEW.province_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
        UPDATE statistics SET province_id = NEW.province_id WHERE city_id = NEW.id;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Create a trigger on city**

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_null_province_reference
AFTER UPDATE ON city
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_null_province_reference();
```

Comment: You've shown the behavior that occurs, but you have not explained what you *expect* to occur.  Please do so.  Explain what "does not work" means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing unexpected happening here, and in fact the `NULL` value is the reason.

When you execute the following `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE city SET province_id = 3 WHERE id = 1
```

Postgre detects that the `(id, country_id, province_id)` combination has changed in the `city` table, and then looks for the record with the same values in the `statistics` table, in this case the tuple `(1, 1, 1)`.  This record is found, and so Postgres also updates the `statistics` table.

*However*, when you execute this `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE city SET province_id = 7 WHERE id = 2
```

Postgres performs the `UPDATE` on the record with the `(id, country_id, province_id)` tuple having the values `(2, 2, NULL)`.  But Postgres cannot verify that a matching record exists in the `statistics` table.  The reason for this has to do with the meaning of `NULL`.  In relational algebra, `NULL` means "not known."  So Postgres sees a `NULL` and gives up on the cascade because it cannot verify that the `NULL` `province_id` in the `city` table in fact matches the `NULL` value in the `statistics` table.